# Using dynamic data with tabs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tabs, selection, jquery-tabs

this sounds so easy - but I just can't figure out the syntax.

I have a tab with multiple sortable lists.

But focusing on the tabs. When a tab is clicked I would like to perform various actions. This can be achieved as below.

```
$( '#tabs' ).tabs({ 
   selected: '<?php echo 'tabs-'.$iTabSelected ?>',
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    // actions performed
   } 
});
```

What's holding me back is, how do I get the id of the li element which makes up my tab:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div>
        <div class="tabs">
        <ul id="pui-tabs">

        <?php foreach( $aTabListData as $iKey => $aTabList ) { ?>

            <li id="tab-<?php echo $aTabList['tab'] ?>">

                    <a href="#tabs-<?php echo $aTabList['tab'] ?>"><?php echo $aTabList['name'] ?></a>
            </li>
```

I'm trying to get the following id when a tab is selected.

```
<li id="tab-<?php echo $aTabList['tab'] ?>">
```

Can I use `ui.tab` to get the li id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select method actually takes two arguments:

```
$( '#tabs' ).tabs({ 
   selected: '<?php echo 'tabs-'.$iTabSelected ?>',
   select: function(event, ui) {
      // Objects available in the function context:
      ui.tab     // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
      ui.panel   // element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
      ui.index   // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
   } 
});
```

Comment: thanks - i've actually already seen this example. The index doesn't get the right tab just the order and ui.tab returns the url with tab appended. The tab appended is actually the anchor tab which contains a different id to the li id.

Comment: i'm looking for something like ui.tab.(give me the pui-tabs li id that is selected)

Comment: I've also tryed: 
$( '#pui-tabs li' ).click({ etc but the anchor is stopping the click from firing!

Comment: Can you post exactly what you get from ui.tab?  What do you mean by "url with tab appended" ? The html of the tab is appended?

Comment: Hi - when I alert ui.tab in the example above i get: http://myproject.local/home/dashboard#tabs-5
#tabs-5 being the anchor href tag within my li.

I need the li id.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe that is a valid function. I was myself trying combinations of that earlier.

Comment: i've managed to get the anchor and split the href to give me the tab number. Not a great solution but it will work.

Comment: I managed to work it out. For those of you who are interested here is the solution:

    $( '#tabs' ).tabs({
     selected: '<?php echo 'tabs-'.$iTabSelected ?>',
     select: function( event, ui ) {
      orderTab( 'pui-tabs', $(ui.tab).closest('li').attr('id') );
     }
    });

This basically gets the closest li tag id which is what I needed.